# How to fix Ldap connection error "javax.naming.SizeLimitExceededException: [LDAP: error code 4 - Sizelimit Exceeded]" in Java?

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

There are 7563 Employees in AD. I need to pick them all using (employeeId=*)

Following is my Java code for the same:

```
        Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<>();
        ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL);
        ldapEnv.put("com.sun.jndi.Ldap.connect.timeout", CONNECTION_TIMEOUT); // specify timeout out to be 5 seconds
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, AUTHENTICATION_TYPE);
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, AD_USER);
        ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, AD_PASS);
        DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv); // initial context created
        System.out.println("(employeeID=" + aDemployeeID + ")");
        String searchFilter = "(employeeID=*)";
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        String[] requiredAttribute = { "mail", "Targetaddress", "UserPrincipalName" };
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        controls.setReturningAttributes(requiredAttribute);
        controls.setCountLimit(1200);

        NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> users1 = context.search(SEARCH_DIRECTORY_1, searchFilter, controls);

        adAttributesToEVRYIntegrator = new HashMap<>();
        int count = 0;
        while (users1.hasMore()) {
            SearchResult sr = users1.next();

            NamingEnumeration<? extends Attribute> aDattributes = sr.getAttributes().getAll();
            count = count + 1;
            while (aDattributes.hasMore()) {
                Attribute requestedAttributesFromAD = aDattributes.next();
                System.out.println(requestedAttributesFromAD.get().toString());
            System.out.println(count);

        }
```

Output:

```
 After 1000 Records:
 javax.naming.SizeLimitExceededException: [LDAP: error code 4 - Sizelimit Exceeded]; remaining name 'OU=Users,OU=Sweden,OU=CCD,OU=Customers,DC=corp,DC=corpcommon,DC=com'
```

I have checked in multiple folder and i found that:

- By Default, LDAP is returning 1000 Records.

Could anyone suggest how to get all records from LDAP

- In Single Go
- In Batches (as i do not have employee Id's with me so how to check that records already came does not come again when using *)

PS: I have done all changes in related posts but not able to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`PagedResultsControl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/ldap/PagedResultsControl.html). You will have to change the declaration of `context` so it's an `LdapContext`, and you can pass the `PagedResultsControl` in the constructor of `InitialLdapContext`:

```
int pageSize = 1000;
LdapContext context = new InitialLdapContext(ldapEnv, new Control[] {
    new PagedResultsControl(pageSize, Control.CRITICAL) });
```

The `pageSize` can be anything <= 1000.

Comment: I have already used this way but it is extremely slow like 100 records are getting fetched in minutes and i have to fetch 7,000 records. When i do not use this way then 1,000 records (before exception) take a few ms to 1 second only. Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: You could try changing your search filter. The `employeeId` attribute is not indexed, so it will have to look at *every* object on your domain (even computer, OU objects, etc.) to check if it has the `employeeId` populated. So you can add `objectClass` (which is indexed) to the filter to limit it to just users. That should speed up the search. For example: `(&(objectClass=user)(employeeId=*))`

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are encountering the Microsoft Active Directory [MaxPageSize](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/MaxPageSize) setting which controls the maximum number of objects that are returned in a single search result.

You can not change the MaxPageSize from the client.

The recommendation from Microsoft is to use the Simple Paged Results Control which will work.

I did notice that you have:

> controls.setCountLimit(1200);

Which set the maximum number of entries to be returned as a result on the Client.

Comment: If if removed then also it is taking 1000 default. You are correct PagedResultControl solves problem.